# Powershell - Within Powershell ISE run multiple line script in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a script that runs in Powershell ISE but there is a part of that script that has to run in regular Powershell.  The script that needs to run in Powershell has multiple lines.

When I try running the script like this:

```
<#
Some code runs up here
#>

$script = {
$PW = "Password1";
$PW = $PW | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force;
Add-SQLAssessmentTask -ManagementGroup "SOME_ID_NUMBER"  -SQLServerName $env:computername -WorkingDirectory C:\Temp\SQL -ScheduledTaskUsername domain\user -ScheduledTaskPassword $PW -Verbose;
}

$command = $script.ToString()

#Start-Process powershell -argumentlist $command

Start-Process powershell -argumentlist $script
```

I get the follow error:
[image]

When I run the script like this:

```
<#
Some code runs up here
#>

$arguments = "$PW = ""Password1""","$PW = $PW | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force","Add-SQLAssessmentTask -ManagementGroup ""SOME_ID_NUMBER""  -SQLServerName $env:computername -WorkingDirectory C:\Temp\SQL -ScheduledTaskUsername domain\user -ScheduledTaskPassword $PW -Verbose" 

Start-Process powershell -argumentlist $arguments
```

I get this error:
[image]

If I run each line in regular Powershell, one at a time, it works fine.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$Arguments` is supposed to be a script block separated by semi-colons if you want to run multiple commands.

```
$arguments = {"$PW = ""Password1""";"$PW = $PW | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force";"Add-SQLAssessmentTask -ManagementGroup ""SOME_ID_NUMBER""  -SQLServerName $env:computername -WorkingDirectory C:\Temp\SQL -ScheduledTaskUsername domain\user -ScheduledTaskPassword $PW -Verbose" }

Start-Process powershell -argumentlist $arguments
```

Comment: I had to create additional variables to hold the "SOME_ID_NUMBER" and working directory, but that did work!